# How to filter a django queryset using case insensitive __in?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a model:

```py
class Skill(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    icon = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=7)
```

I want to do the following filter, but case insensitive:

```py
skill_names = ['Code Quality', 'Analytical Thinking', 'Productivity', 'Communication']
Skill.objects.filter(name__in=skill_names)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar problem and this helped me

```
from operator import or_
from functools import reduce
from django.db.models import Q

skill_names = ['Code Quality', 'Analytical Thinking', 'Productivity', 'Communication']
skill_filter = reduce(
    or_, (Q(name__icontains=skill) for skill in skill_names)
)
Skill.objects.filter(skill_filter)
```

Comment: ```Skill.objects.filter(name__in=skill_filter)``` gives the following error

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: operator does not exist: character varying = boolean
LINE 1: ...at" FROM "skill_skill" WHERE "skill_skill"."name" IN (UPPER(...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```
```Skill.objects.filter(skill_filter)``` works fine

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from django.db.models import Q

skill_names = ['Code Quality', 'Analytical Thinking', 'Productivity', 'Communication']

query = Q()

for skill in skill_names:
    query |= Q(name__contains=skill)

Skill.objects.filter(query)
```

Comment: You might forget to make the filer __icontains